# how can I make BottomNavigationBar stick on top of keyboard flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make a simple chat app, so I created a scaffold and my body, will be the messages and my `bottomNavigationBar` would be my typing field and sending icon.

I added a text field but when typing the navigation bar is hidden by the keyboard.

this is the code of my `BottomNavigationBar` :

```
bottomNavigationBar: new Container(
          height: ScreenSize.height/12,
          /*color: Colors.red,*/

          child: new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,

            children: <Widget>[
              new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    child: new Icon(Icons.send),

                    width:ScreenSize.width/6,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Material(
                    child: new Container(
                      child: new TextField(
                        autofocus: false,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: 'Please enter a search term',
                        ),
                      ),
                      width:ScreenSize.width*4/6,
                    ),
                      elevation: 4.0,
                    /*borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(45.0)),*/
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    type: MaterialType.card,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    child: Text('HELLO C1'),
                    color: Colors.green,
                    width:ScreenSize.width/6,
                  ),
                ],
              )




            ],
          ),
        ),
```

here is how it looks when focused :

[image]

Answer (score 34):

simply wrap your bottom navigation bar with  Padding and set it to MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,

```html
  bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
       padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
        child: ChatInputField(),
     ),
```

Answer (score 22):

if you use a Stack on your Scaffold's body, instead of bottomNavigationBar, your nav will push up above the keyboard.  even if you fix to the bottom with a Positioned:

```
Positioned(
   bottom: 0.0,
   left: 0.0,
   right: 0.0,
   child: MyNav(),
),
```

Comment: great way to implement! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Literally just worked through the same issue.  Given the code i was refactoring, this worked like a charm.  Peep the github link, review his change and apply.  Couldn't be much more straight forward: https://github.com/GitJournal/GitJournal/commit/f946fe487a18b2cb8cb1d488026af5c64a8f2f78..

Content of the link above in case the link goes down:

```
(-)BottomAppBar buildEditorBottonBar(
(+)Widget buildEditorBottonBar(
  BuildContext context,
  Editor editor,
  EditorState editorState,
BottomAppBar buildEditorBottonBar(
    folderName = "Root Folder";
  }

  *REPLACE* return BottomAppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
    color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.folder),
          label: Text(folderName),
          onPressed: () {
            var note = editorState.getNote();
            editor.moveNoteToFolderSelected(note);
          },
        )
      ],
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

  *WITH THE WRAPPER* return StickyBottomAppBar(
    child: BottomAppBar(
      elevation: 0.0,
      color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.folder),
            label: Text(folderName),
            onPressed: () {
              var note = editorState.getNote();
              editor.moveNoteToFolderSelected(note);
            },
          )
        ],
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class StickyBottomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final BottomAppBar child;
  StickyBottomAppBar({@required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(0.0, -1 * MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great solution with that Transform widget!

Answer (score -2):

If you need some kind of button; you can do:

```dart
Scaffold(
            bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
            floatingActionButton: ExampleButton(
              text: 'Hello',
            ),
            body: body,
          ),
```

You can apply further customizations on the Floating Action Button using parameters in the Scaffold.

Answer (score -2):

I achieved this by a mix of two things I found separated in the web:

1 - Inside the Scaffold, I put other with only a bottomNavigationBar with a empty Container. For some reason, this trick push all my real bottomNavigationBar up to the top of the keyboard.

```
Scaffold(
 bottomNavigationBar: Container(
   height: 0,
 ),
   body: Scaffold(
body: MyWidget(
```

But, I did not want all the content up, so I got that Package:

2 - I added flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^5.1.0 from

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility

With this Package, you can do anything you want in response to keyboard visibility - is up to you. In my case, I made all content of my real bottomNavigationBar disappear except the textfield, which stay on the top of the keyboard:

[TextFormField] // dont go away,
//The others:

```
KeyboardVisibilityBuilder(builder: (context, visible) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            visible
                ? SizedBox(
                    height: 0,
                  )
                : OtherWidgets(
```

Answer (score -3):

There is a simple way to do this if you want to really need to use the bottom navigation bar of the scaffold to put your widgets in rather than put it on a stack. Just wrap your scaffold with another scaffold and it should solve the problem.

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: yourBottomNavigationBarWidget(),
        body: yourBody(),
```

This works best especially when the height of your widget changes dynamically (because the text user types may introduce multiple lines) and you want the body to resize accordingly. A body in the stack, as suggested by many, will require a bottom padding to be visible over the text field and need to change dynamically as user types which is difficult to handle when you have multiple widgets sitting in and around the text field.